# Library for interactive time series charting

Tags: c++, r, visualization, time-series, libraries

For my recent project I am looking to build a software capable of visualizing financial charts in a dynamically and interactive matter. The workflow is as follows:

1. I gather data from my data provider of choice (real-time, asynchronous)
2. I do some statistical analysis of my data (mostly using R and C)
3. From (2) I get a new bunch of different time series data that I'd like to visualize (chart) using some nice GUI/ Rendering.

As you'd guess step 3 drives me nuts. I've found a bunch of nice APIs for Browser based visualization like [StockChart SL](http://www.modulusfe.com/stockchartsl/) or [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) but what I really need seems to be rare: A library for an arbitrary programming language that I can use to build a standalone application. My needs are simple yet slightly different from "common" plotting libraries: I want it to be able to interact with the chart (thus, paning and if possible zooming), to be able to update the chart dynamically as new input data arrives (async.), and to be able to add "objects" to the Charts like standard deviations or moving averages (I don't need the library for the calculations but for the drawing).

However, there is one more additional requirement: The software should come with a free license for non-commercial applications as I am not willing to pay before I am perfectly comfortable with it).

Does anyone happen to know or worked with a library like this?

Comment: A web app using D3.js would be perfect for this kind of application. Why the limit on using a web app?

Comment: I planned to let the software communicate via dll's with other programs so I thought that would be a hard thing to do with a web app, right?

Comment: PS: And as I am veeery unfamiliar with JS and web-apps in general I don't know if it is easy to preprocess the data in C or R and then pass it to be visualized by ,e.g., D3js

Comment: Communication in a webapp is typically through http. A piece of JavaScipt code runs in the web browser of the user, requesting data from a server, i.e. a web server with a database as a backend. That database could filled using any tool, e.g. using C or R.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) libraries for chart plotting (that includes all the requirement you mentioned) together with [Qt 4.8x SDK](http://qt-project.org/) as the underlying GUI platform. Both libraries have license that can meet your needs.